# Count number of orders *ordered* after an specific order ID in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

We are trying to implement a prize for the 10th user ordering from the website.

But it is **not all time** user orders. The contest start today so we need to count the number of orders **after** the last order last night.

I have the order id of the order last night.

How can I achieve this?

So far I have this:

```
$args = array();

$args['numberposts'] = 10;

$args['status'] = array( 'wc-completed', );

$args['ADDITIONAL_PARAMETER'] = ADDITIONAL_PARAMETER; /* orders after and specific order */

$orders = wc_get_orders( $args );
```

Can you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `wc_get_orders` and `WC_Order_Query` that provide a standard way of retrieving orders that is safe to use and will not break due to database changes in future WooCommerce versions.

Source: [wc_get_orders and WC_Order_Query](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query) - Just pass a series of arguments that define the criteria for the search.

So you get:

```php
// Order ID last night
$order_id_last_night = 2448;

// Get $order object
$order_last_night = wc_get_order( $order_id_last_night );

// Get date created
$order_last_night_date_created = $order_last_night->get_date_created();

// Get 10 order IDs after date last night
$orders_ids = wc_get_orders( array(
    'status'       => array( 'wc-completed' ),
    'limit'        => 10,
    'orderby'      => 'date',
    'order'        => 'ASC',
    'date_created' => '>' . strtotime( $order_last_night_date_created ),
    'return'       => 'ids',
));
 
// Consists of 10
if( count( $orders_ids) == 10 ) {
    // Returns the value of the last element
    echo end( $orders_ids );
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I love you pal.